# Android build custom certificates prompt for password ANDROID_PW_FILE

Tags: android, python, android-build

I'm building Android from Source and use custom certificates. Now I get prompted for the Password each time a app is signed by the buildsystem.

Is there any way to avoid this?

I've stumbled upon the ANDROID_PW_FILE and used it by exporting it before a build. I used an empty File and a File with the following content:

```
[[[ password ]]] build/target/product/security/platform.pk8
.... More lines like this with same syntax....
```

But without success. I get prompted everytime. 
If i run

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv("ANDROID_PW_FILE", None))
<<< /build/target/product/security/PASSWD
```

I can see the envvar is set. I also exported `EDITOR=vim` but I don't really understand what this should do. I've just noticed that the `build/tools/releasetools/common.py` checks if both are set and Prompts otherwise.

Any suggestions?

Comment: setting EDITOR worked for me, but I used the full path.
export EDITOR=$(which vim)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved this by eliminating whitespace from the file and eliminating the extensions.  I basically did a copy/paste from the password prompt.

For example, if my password is abc123 my file is

```
[[[abc123]]]vendor/company/security/product/releasekey
[[[abc123]]]vendor/company/security/product/platform
[[[abc123]]]vendor/company/security/product/shared
[[[abc123]]]vendor/company/security/product/media
```